# Putting presentation data in angular controller?

Tags: angularjs

Got a webapp I'm building in Angular.

This app walks a user to authorizing accounts, presenting specific instructions based on the users choices.

I've implemented this as HTML that is shown or hidden based on values in the model, so for 3 different choices, I have 3 different sets of HTML sections that are similar but with different texts.

In the spirit of DRY, I should instead have one set of HTML sections, and instead switch the text based on the values of the model. This means putting text data inside the model, including small snippets of markup, like anchor and strong tags.

Does putting presentation data into the controller violate the principals of Angular?

Comment: Have you considered directives with templates? I don't sufficiently understand the question so as to advise better. A short code example might help.

Comment: K, Let me create a js fiddle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a number of options to avoid repeating code depending on what you are looking to do. The following ideas are things I would consider and use when they make sense (*I placed these from simple to complex, so you probably can skip the first few*):

- **ng-bind** -- Put it on a span/div. Simple & works to bind the model to the display
- **ng-switch, ng-if, ng-hide, ng-show** -- Work to conditionally show an element
- **custom directive** -- use this when you want to alter the behavior of an element *or* if you want to alter the dom based on a template. If you use "[ng-transclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angTransclude)" the contents of the element you template will be included in the result. This can be very elegant but it works best when you have a single format. I can provide examples but angular's documentation also has excellent examples.
- **service** -- I generally use this just to provide data only. This could be via a restful api and $resource or via $http calls. Either way, I wouldn't recommend doing much more than load/save data here.
- **$scope method** -- In other words:

  $scope.myMethod = function(x,y,z) { /* code making decisions based on the model */ }

  Then you can call this method from one of the previous either via a prebuilt directive (ng-show, etc) or via a custom directive that manipulates the dom for how you expect it to be.
- **ng-bind-html** -- Last option I know to suggest is to use this directive combined with the [$sce](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce) service to bind whatever you want to the DOM. If you are binding something with angular code in it - make sure to use the [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) service as well. I generally don't favor this approach except as a last resort because it makes it harder to find where elements in the DOM are coming from and it can make debugging + testing a real pain. That said, these tools wouldn't exist if people didn't need them.

I'm sure that this isn't complete and maybe others have suggestions but that is where I would start. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would put the text data in a separate angular service. This article gives an example: http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/04/24/modeling-data-and-state-in-your-angularjs-application/

Then if you decided at some point to move it to some other storage, your service would still be the single access point for the rest of the app.